# my css doesn't work on mobile browers however it work on resized desktop browsers well

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using an plugin to add social sharing buttons on my site [wondertacular.com](http://www.wondertacular.com/facebook-on-old-phone/). They looks great on wide screens but in small screens they look messed up. So I added following css to override default css and make those two big horizontal sharing buttons responsive.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .essb_displayed_both li {
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    }
}
```

It works well when I resize desktop browsers (chrome and ff) to small width window but when I open this page in mobile browsers (chrome, FF, Opera) I didn't see any changes. It seems my css does not apply in mobile browsers. Please refer following screenshots -

Buttons are broken in mobile view 
http://itsfromindia.net/mobile.png

While they looks good on desktop browsers when resized to small window.
http://itsfromindia.net/desktop.jpg

Please tell me whats going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `meta` tag in the `<head>` that tells mobile browsers not to scale your site.

Add this in the `<head>` of your document and it should work as you're expecting:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

More information [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Comment: Wanted to add for those who might happen across this question that you may still get the OP's described behavior on some small device viewports if you don't add an initial scale. I think it's poor browser rendering engine implementations surrounding scaling related code. For that reason and to disable scaling in general, I prefer to use:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding browser specific CSS, like:

-webkit- (safari/chrome)

-o- (opera)

-ms- (IE)

-moz- (firefox)

It helps make your CSS cross-browser compatible and can help on your mobile browsers.

```
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
     .essb_displayed_both li {
         display: block;
         white-space: nowrap;

         -webkit-margin-bottom: 20px;
         -o-margin-bottom: 20px;
         -ms-margin-bottom: 20px;
         -moz-margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
  }
```

Not sure if that's the solution but it can't hurt!

Comment: Its not just about margin-bottom, everything is not working in mobiles. And as far as I know margin bottom works on all mobile browsers without browser specific CSS.

Comment: Could you provide code? jsfiddle maybe? Looks like you have some inline styles, they could be overriding some of your mobile styles.

Comment: Also maybe this will be helpful http://alistapart.com/article/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet